# php unable to remove item from array

Tags: php

I have got a shopping cart class, where I can store the same product ID with multiple attributes such as different sizes for the same product. However, when having multiple items in my array of the same product ID and removing each 1 by one, I find sometimes 1 or 2 of the items i cannot remove from the array. i can remove some of the items but not all.

button to remove item

```
<div class="removebtn" data-id="'.$id.'" data-qty="'.$item['quantity'].'" data-price="'.((isset($item['attributes']['price'])) ? $item['attributes']['price'] : '').'"  data-size="'.((isset($item['attributes']['size'])) ? $item['attributes']['size'] : '').'" >
```

ajax to remove item

```
$('.removebtn').on('click', function(){
  var $btn = $(this);
  var id = $btn.attr('data-id');
  var size = $btn.attr('data-size');
  var price = $btn.attr('data-price');
  var qty = $btn.attr('data-qty');
 var action = "remove";
    $.ajax ({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'mycart.php',
      data: {

        id: id,
        size:size,
        action: action,
        price:price,
        qty:qty                               
      },
```

funciton to remove

```
/**
 * Remove item from cart.
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @param array  $attributes
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function remove($id, $attributes = [])
{
    if (!isset($this->items[$id])) {
        return false;
    }

    if (empty($attributes)) {
        unset($this->items[$id]);

        $this->write();

        return true;
    }
    $hash = md5(json_encode(array_filter($attributes)));
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($this->items[$id] as $item) {
        if ($item['hash'] == $hash) {
            unset($this->items[$id][$index]);

            $this->write();

            return true;
        }
        ++$index;
    }

    return false;
}
```

mycart.php

```
if ($_POST["action"] == 'remove') {
    $cart->remove($_POST['id'],[
        'price' => $_POST['price'],
        'size' => (isset($_POST['size'])) ? $_POST['size'] : '',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: lol sorry, basically, each item has a remove button, but for some reason some items can be removed and others just wont get removed from the array

Comment: It's possible that your indexes run out of sync. You could try: `foreach ($this->items[$id] as $index => $item) {` and remove `++$index`. But that's really just a guess from me.

Comment: nah sorry that doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of counting on your own, you should use the key from your foreach loop, as unset leaves empty spots.

```
$array = [1,2,3];
unset($array[1]);
```

At this point, `$array[1]` isn't set, so your manual counting wont work. So just use this

```
foreach ($this->items[$id] as $index => $item) {
    ...
}
```

In addition to that, the way you calculate the hash doesn't seem very robust and strongly relies on the order of your input array. I would change this too..